# Connecting to remote interpreter when starting PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-access, interpreter

I have a remote interpreter set up in PyCharm.

**Everytime I close and reopen PyCharm, the connection seems to be broken, and the process to "reopen" the connection doesn't feel efficient to me.**

Before doing the following, it is not possible to run any script.

Here is what I usually do:

1. File -­> Settings
2. Project -> Project Interpreter
3. Click on the gear icon on the right.
4. Choose "More"
5. With my remote interpreter selected, click on "Edit"
6. Change "SSH Credentials" for "Deployment Configuration" (all the info is already filled)
7. Click "ok" multiple times to close everything up.

At that point, I can run any scripts on the remote machine.

What is the best/fastest way to do this? (any way to "save the settings"?)

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not possible to run any script"? What exactly happens when you try?

Comment: @yole: Error running name_of_script:<br>Can't run remote python interpreter: Error connecting to remote host:XXX.XX.XX.XX

Comment: This definitely looks like a bug in PyCharm. Which version are you using? If you still have the problem with the latest one (4.0.3), could you please file a bug report at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com?

Comment: @yole: updating to 4.0.3 fixed the problem.

Comment: Getting the same problem with another computer (even with newer version!). Removing the answer tag.

Answer (score 6):

Check option "Visible only for this project" of deployment configuration. This error occurs when the check mark is set.

> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2018.3/deployment-connection-tab.html
>
> if this checkbox is selected in an SFTP configuration, you cannot use
>   its SSH credentials for configuring a remote interpreter.

Comment: I have the box unchecked and the problem still occurs for me

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in version 4.0.2 of PyCharm and was corrected in version 4.0.3.

Edit: No longer true. I tried with another computer and having the most recent version doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score -2):

i meet the same error, `file->settings` checking your interpreter setting,

You don't set the 'host' and 'post',or your set but the content was clear. check again, and it truly work